# Why is $y^2 = 4ax$ considered as the standard form of a parabola?

Tags: notation

Was wondering why $y^2 =4ax$ is considered as the standard form of a parabola?
I was going through my textbook and all important results like equation of Tangent, Normal, Chord of contact was given in terms of $y^2 = 4ax$ form.  So is there any way to convert between them?

Comment: I believe that traditional form is used because then $a$ is the distance between the vertex and the focus.

Comment: Probably because the standard formula is in fact a special case of general formula for  parabola, ellipse and hyperbola: $y^2=2px-(1-  \epsilon^2)x^2$ in which $\epsilon =0$  and $p =2a$ for parabola.

Comment: @Mahadev If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By **switching the axes**:  $$y^2 =4ax$$ is totally equivalent to $$x^2 =4ay \implies y=\frac{x^2} {4a}$$.

Comment: I am given a formula for equation of tangent at a specific point (x1,y1) on parabola y^2=4ax as yy1=2a(x+x1) how would I write a similar equation for x^2=4ay?

Comment: For $y^2=4ax$ the tangent at $(x_1,y_1)$  should be $y-y_1=2a(x-x_1)$.

Comment: The most widely used form is $y=4ax^2$ with x as horizontal axis and y vertical. In this case the parabola is concave up.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any parabola into any other parabola by completing the squares and shifting around. For instance, you are given

$$x=Ay^2+By+C$$
You first complete the square:
$$x=A(y^2+(B/A)y+C/A)=A(y+B/(2A))^2+C/A-B^2/(4A)^2$$
Rewrite

$$(y-y_0)^2=A^{-1}(x-x_0)$$
where $y_0=-B/(2A)$ is how much the parabola is moved in $y$ direction from the standard form, $x_0=C/A-B^2/(4A)^2$ is how much it is moved in $x$ direction and $A^{-1}$ is the equivalent of your $4a$ parameter.

If your parabola has $x$ in squares and $y$ in linear terms, just exchange $x$ and $y$.